# print lines between "End" keyword in a file

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

starting from the first occurrence of the word "End" till the last occurrence of the word "End", need to grep all lines between it

In a file grep lines between End keyword

Consider Input file with below lines

```
one
two
----End-----
two
three
---End-----
four
ten
---End-----
six
seven
```

Expected Output:

```
----End-----
two
three
---End-----
four
ten
---End-----
```

Comment: at least, post the input file

Comment: have edited the question

Comment: Crossposted on UL (where it belongs): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/390091/need-to-print-all-lines-between-end-lines

Comment: yes because in that url i am not having access to add comment and hence

Comment: i believe the question is very clear with all input file and expected output also in it. If its not unclear, please let me know

Comment: `sed -n -e '/End/,$!d' -e 'H;/End/{g;s/^\n//;p;s/.*//;h;}' filenamr`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '
/End/ {                        # at End
    print (b==""?"":b ORS) $0  # print buffer and End line
    f=1                        # flag up
    b=""                       # reset buffer
    next
}
f {                            # after first End 
    b=b (b==""?"":ORS) $0      # gather the buffer
}' file
----End-----
two
three
---End-----
four
ten
---End-----
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` and `tac` (from GNU coreutils):

```
$ sed -n '/End/,$p' file | tac | sed -n '/End/,$p' | tac    
----End-----
two
three
---End-----
four
ten
---End-----
```

The first `sed` only allows the lines from the first delimiter to the end of file to get through.  `tac` reverses the order of the lines in the result.

The `sed` and `tac` is then repeated.